# Find a bijective function that maps integers to rationals $f: \Bbb Z\rightarrow \Bbb Q$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How would you go about creating a function that maps these sets? I understand that it exists and why it exists but I can't think of a way to accurately represent the function. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The question was not exactly the same but in the first answer you can see a bijection between $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Easiest is to create injections in the two directions, then use the construction for the Schröder-Bernstein theorem.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schröder–Bernstein_theorem

Comment: "I understand that it exists and why it exists"  Why *does* it exist?  If you can explain why, you may get it. The standard is to muck around with a diangonal path between $\mathbb Q\to \mathbb N \times \mathbb N\to\mathbb N \to \mathbb Z$ via $\frac ab\to (a,b)\to$ number of steps to weave to $(a,b)$by following diagonals  via taking sums$\to $ some manipulations to alternate negs and positive,   and omit the ones  where $\gcd(a,b)\ne 1$.

Comment: Thank you all very much for your responses. They definitely help get me there!

Comment: I think that the linked question in the comment of @Mark is pretty much exactly the same: instead of asking to "accurately represent the function" it asks to "produce an explicit formula for a bijection". Voting to close as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Bear with me.  This one will be weird.

If $q\in \mathbb Q$ then either $q = 0$ or there are $a,b\in \mathbb N$ so that $q =\pm \frac ab$ and $\gcd(a,b) = 1$.

Now if $q=\pm ab\ne 0$, $a,b> 0$ then $a,b$ have unique prime factorizations and because $\gcd(a,b) =1$ then have no prime terms in common.

Let $a =\prod p_i^{k_i}$ and $b= \prod q_j^{m_j}$ be those prime factors.

Map $\pm \frac{\prod p_i^{k_i}}{\prod q_j^{m_j}}\mapsto \pm\prod p_i^{2k_i}q_j^{2m_j - 1}$.

And map $0 \mapsto 0$.

That'll do it. Because every positive non-zero integer has a unique prime factorization there is a positive rational that maps to it.  And because $a,b$ share no factors in common and the factorizations of $a,b$ are unique each different rational is mapped to different integer.

Negative integers map from unique negative rationals as they are just negative "reflections" of their positive counterparts.

And $0$ maps to and and is the only rational that maps to $0$.

Comment: Thank you fleablood this is very helpful.

Comment: It's not the standard.  The standard is the diagonal argument where you draw a grid and travel the diagonals one by one.

Comment: I think you need to map $0$ to $0$ explicitly. Nice argument though.

Comment: @MitchellSpector Oh!  Good point but $0\mapsto 0$ will do it.